# ThreadLocal <T> - What is a thread? (C#)

Tags: c#, multithreading

I'm struggling with multithreading in C# (which I'm learning just for fun) and realise I probably don't understand what a thread is! When I run the code below, I was expecting to get something like the following output.

```
T1: 11
T2: 11
T3: 11
T4: 11
T5: 11
T6: 11
```

(possibly in a different order)

However, I'm getting something like

```
T1: 11
T2: 11
T3: 12
T5: 12
T6: 13
T4: 11
```

I had assumed that each task (T1 to T6) would be a new thread and therefore each instance of "local" would be initialised to 10 and incremented by one. But it certainly doesn't look like this is happening. If anyone can explain what is going on and what I am incorrectly assuming, I'd be very grateful. 
(I must admit I'm finding it difficult to come to grips with threading because I can't find anything basic enough to start from!)

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TestThreads
{

    class TestThreadLocal
    {

        static void Main()
        {
            ThreadLocal<int> local = new ThreadLocal<int>(() =>
            {   return 10;
            });

            Task t1 = Task.Run(() =>
            {   local.Value++;
                Console.WriteLine("T1: " + local.Value);
            });

            Task t2 = Task.Run(() =>
            {   local.Value++;
                Console.WriteLine("T2: " + local.Value);
            });
            Task t3 = Task.Run(() =>
            {   local.Value++;
                Console.WriteLine("T3: " + local.Value);
            });

            Task t4 = Task.Run(() =>
            {   local.Value++;
                Console.WriteLine("T4: " + local.Value);
            });

            Task t5 = Task.Run(() =>
            {   local.Value++;
                Console.WriteLine("T5: " + local.Value);
            });

            Task t6 = Task.Run(() =>
            {   local.Value++;
                Console.WriteLine("T6: " + local.Value);
            });

            Task.WaitAll(t1, t2, t3, t4, t5, t6);
            local.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Tasks != Threads. One of the main points of tasks is to portion up units of work and *not care* about threading details for how they run

Comment: My guess is that since `Task.Run` uses **thread pool**, some tasks are run on the same thread, if this thread had managed to complete the previous task.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn906268(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: When I read "Tasks != Threads", I went "aHA!". That makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason is `Task.Run` uses thread pool, which means it grabs some free thread from the pool of already existing threads, does work on it, and *returns it back* (in simplified terms). So it's perfectly possible that one or more of subsequent Tas.Run operations will run on the same thread. Easiest way to verify it is to print current thread id:

```
Task.Run(() => {
   local.Value++;
   Console.WriteLine("Thread id: {0}, value: {1}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId, local.Value);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Evk - that makes perfect sense and is clearly explained. It's exactly what I needed to know. Thanks too for the hint about adding thread ID as it makes it even clearer.